# removing the last comma in for loops (java)

Tags: java

I'm new to coding and I'm trying to remove the last comma for my last loop.
It would be great if I can get help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner dev = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1, num2;
        num1 = dev.nextInt();
        num2 = dev.nextInt();

        int numa = 1;
        System.out.println();
        for (numa = num1; numa <= 100; numa++) {
            if (numa / num1 == 1 && numa % num1 == 0)
                System.out.print(numa);
            else if (numa % num1 == 0)
                System.out.print("," + numa);

        }
        int numb = 1;
        System.out.println();
        for (numb = num2; numb <= 100; numb++) {
            if (numb / num2 == 1 && numb % num2 == 0)
                System.out.print(numb);
            else if (numb % num2 == 0)
                System.out.print("," + numb);

        }

        int numc = 1;
        System.out.println();
        for (numc = num1; numc <= 100; numc++) {
            if(numc / num2 == 2 && numb % num2 == 0)
                System.out.print(numc);
            else if(numc % num1 == 0 && numc % num2 == 0)
                System.out.print(numc + ",");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could print the comma when `numa` (or `numb` or `numc` depending on where you need to remove the last comma) is less than `100`, e.g. `if(numa < 100) { System.out.println(','); }` the last iteration where `numa == 100` will then not print the comma

Comment: You could also use `java.util.StringJoiner` which is best suited for your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend the following as much more standard, and therefore, for long-time java programmers, readable (uses `i` for integer loop counter, prefers counting to `<` instead of `<=`, simplifies math expressions):

```
    System.out.println();
    boolean lastWasEqual = false;
    for (int i = num1; i < 101; i++) {
        boolean isHalf = (2 * i == num2);  // a/b = 2 <=> 2a = b
        boolean isEqual = (i == num2);     // (a%b) = (b%a) = 0 <=> a = b
        
        if (isHalf || isEqual) {
           if (lastWasEqual) {
              System.out.print(","); 
           }
           System.out.print(i);
           lastWasEqual = isEqual;
        }
    }
```

The idea here is that we only output a `,` once we know that (a) it was ready to be printed (`lastWasEqual`) and (b) there will be output after it (so that "the last comma" is never printed).

By looking at the math, you can see that `isEqual` will be true at most once, and `isHalf` will also be true at most once. And it is easy to see *when* they will be true. So there is no need for loops:

```
 System.out.println();
 boolean willReachEqual = (num1 <= num2) && (num2 <= 100);
 boolean willReachHalf  = (num1 * 2 <= num2) 
                       && ((num2 % 2) == 0) && (num2 <= 200);
 boolean willReachBoth = willReachEqual && willReachHalf;

 System.out.println(
           (willReachHalf ? (num2 / 2) : "") + 
           (willReachBoth ? "," : "") + 
           (willReachEqual ? num2 : ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the comment of @Lino, change your last loop to:

```
for (numc = num1; numc <= 100; numc++) {
    if(numc / num2 == 2 && numb % num2 == 0)
        System.out.print(numc);
    else if(numc % num1 == 0 && numc % num2 == 0){
        if(numc < 100) 
            System.out.print(numc + ",");
        else
            System.out.print(numc);
    }
}
```

A better way would be to add the numbers to a list (for example `numbersToPrint`) and then using `Collectors.joining()`:

```
String output = numbersToPrint.stream().map(i-> String.valueOf(i)).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
// output: 1,2,...,100
```

Or using `StringJoiner`:

```
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(",");
sj.add(String.valueOf(1)).add(String.valueOf(2));
String output = sj.toString();
// output: 1,2
```

Or using `String.join`:

```
String output = String.join(",", String.valueOf(1),String.valueOf(2));
// output: 1,2
```

Comment: I think that the problem is not so much how to concatenate a `,` into the output (last answers) but rather how to avoid extra commas at the end (partially addressed by your recommendation to build a list and then print it --- which is overkill if you look at actual output, which can never be of length > 2)